# onTap make itemizedOverlay and activity crashes due to bad constructors

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i have my Mapactivity which addes some items from an overlay items but whenever i tap on an item, it gives me null pointer exception and of course crashes. I've made many researches and all results say that it's due to bad construtors and Context but the problem is that their solutions doesn't work for me. here are some related topics

1. [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319158/googlemaps-mapview-crashes-ontap-in-android)
2. [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572409/hello-google-maps-example-null-pointer-exception)
3. [link3](http://www.anddev.org/map-problems-f26/error-when-trying-to-access-overlay-text-t12324.html?sid=87163bc814ce6ded7400844529c7d7f3#wrap)
   i've tryied, this, this.getApplicationContext but stil, i'have a null pointer ewception

here is where i call my overlayItems in my mapActivity class:

```
 marker1 =getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.maps_position_marker);
        marker1.setBounds( (int) (-marker1.getIntrinsicWidth()/2),
        -marker1.getIntrinsicHeight(),
        (int) (marker1.getIntrinsicWidth()/2),
        0);
        overlay4 notFunPlaces =  new overlay4(marker1, this.getBaseContext());
        mapView.getOverlays().add(notFunPlaces);
       // GeoPoint pt1 = notFunPlaces.getCenterPt();
        int latSpan1 = notFunPlaces.getLatSpanE6();
        int lonSpan1 = notFunPlaces.getLonSpanE6();
        Log.v("Overlays", "Lat span is " + latSpan1);
        Log.v("Overlays", "Lon span is " + lonSpan1);


my itmizedOverlay class class:

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    class overlay4 extends ItemizedOverlay {

        private ArrayList<OverlayItem> locations =
        new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        private Context mContext;
        private PopupPanel panel=new PopupPanel(R.layout.popup);



        public <getBaseContext> overlay4(Drawable marker, getBaseContext context )
        {

            super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
            mContext = (Context) context;
  //  my items
.........
populates();}

 @Override
                protected boolean onTap(int i) {

                  OverlayItem item=getItem(i);
                  GeoPoint geo=item.getPoint();
                  Bitmap bitmap = null;

              Point pro=    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geo, null);
                  if (pro!=null)
                  {   View view=panel.getView();

              String capteur=   getType (locations.get(i).getSnippet()); 
                  ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.poptext))
                    .setText(String.valueOf("image captured by : " + capteur + "\n" + "Latitude = " + locations.get(i).getPoint().getLatitudeE6()/1E6 +" " + "Longitude = "+ locations.get(i).getPoint().getLongitudeE6()/1E6 +" " + 
                             "\n" + "Image can be found at the following directory :" + locations.get(i).getTitle()

                            ));
                  ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageV);
        ........
```

my logcat:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at tfe.rma.ciss.be.TheMap$overlay4.onTap(TheMap.java:3705)
     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
     at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:356)
     at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:533)
     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:683)
     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1750)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1135)
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1734)
     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2216)
     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1887)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
:   Force finishing activity tfe.rma.ciss.be/.TheMap
tate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
:   Force finishing activity tfe.rma.ciss.be/.menu
```

Comment: whats at line 3705 of TheMap.java?

Comment: you can pass mapactivity.this                                 overlay4 notFunPlaces =  new overlay4(marker1, this.getBaseContext());
and why casting in constructors  mContext = (Context) context;